# Probability problem

Tags: probability

A student has to pass 3 out of 4 consecutive test to complete a course. The probability that he
passes in a test is P. If he fails in a test the probability of passing the next test is /2
What is the probability that the student completes the course?

Comment: Just do casework. It's a small number so it won't be hard, and it could give you insight.

Comment: between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303389/locus-of-complex-number-problem) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Comment: Let's try to promote the good habit of ask a question and and tell us something more about what we have tried, about what we have advanced, where we have got stuck. We are here to help each other ;)

Answer (score 2):

$P$ $P$ $P$ $-$

$P$ $P$ $-$ $\frac{P}{2}$

$P$ $-$ $\frac{P}{2}$ $\frac{P}{2}$

$-$ $\frac{P}{2}$ $\frac{P}{2}$ $\frac{P}{2}$

are the four desired outcomes out of 16 (Pass or Fail for 4 times, assume that the student takes all four of them in any case including if it starts with first two Fails).

So, the probability is $(4/16)*(P^3 + P^3/2 + P^3/4 + P^3/8)=15P^3/64$

P.S: I assumed that once the probability reduces to $\frac{P}{2}$ after one Fail, it doesn't go back to $P$ even if the student passes the next test. If you want $\frac{P}{2}$ to increase to $P$ after a Pass, then change the probabilities accordingly.